# When is the Blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^n$ dominant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, rational-functions, blowup

Let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ be some algebraic variety. Lets assume that there are some homogeneous polynomials $f_0,\ldots,f_n$, all of degree $d$, that generate the vanishing ideal of $X$. When is the rational map $\mathbb{P}^n\dashrightarrow\mathbb{P}^n, x\mapsto (f_0(x):\cdots:f_n)$ dominant? Are there some nice criteria? What are examples where it is not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example. Let $A$ and $B$ be vector spaces of dimension 2 and 5. Let
$$
X = \mathbb{P}(A) \times \mathbb{P}(B) \subset \mathbb{P}(A \otimes B).
$$
The ideal of $X$ is generated by quadrics, which span the space
$$
\mathrm{Ker}(S^2(A \otimes B)^\vee \to S^2A^\vee \otimes S^2B^\vee) = \wedge^2A \otimes \wedge^2B \cong \wedge^2B.
$$
Note that $\dim(A \otimes B) = 10 = \dim(\wedge^2B)$.
But the image of the corresponding map
$$
f \colon \mathbb{P}(A \otimes B) \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}(\wedge^2B)
$$
is the Grassmannian
$$
\mathrm{Gr}(2,B) \subset \mathbb{P}(\wedge^2B).
$$